# Shiny -How to save to excel every change in renderTable?

Tags: r, shiny

I use Timevis package.
first of all I read an excel file with missions.
In my code the user can see all the missions on a time line, and he can edit/add/remove any missions.
after the user make a change I can see the update table below.
I want to save to my excel file every update that the user make.
this is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(readxl)
  
  my_df <-  read_excel("x.xlsx")
  data <- data.frame(
    id = my_df$id,
    start = my_df$start,
    end = my_df$end,
    content = my_df$content
  )
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    timevisOutput("appts"),
    tableOutput("table")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$appts <- renderTimevis(
      timevis(
        data,
        options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center")
      )
    )
    

    
    output$table <- renderTable(
      input$appts_data
    )
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `actionButton`/ `observe` to call `saveworkbook` (package [openxlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf)) to save your changes. Technically you are not saving these changes, but replacing the file with an identical file containing the changes.

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(timevis)
library(readxl)

my_df <-  read_excel("x.xlsx")

data <- data.frame(
  id = my_df$id,
  start = my_df$start,
  end = my_df$end,
  content = my_df$content
)

mypath = paste0(getwd(), "/x.xlsx") # Path to x.xlsx

ui <- fluidPage(
  timevisOutput("appts"),
  tableOutput("table"),
  actionButton("save", "Save")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data,
      options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center")
    ))

    observeEvent(input$save, 
    {
      my_df<- createWorkbook()
      
      addWorksheet(
        my_df,
        sheetName = "data"
      )

      writeData(
      wb = my_df,
      sheet = "data",
      x = input$appts_data,
      startRow = 1,
      startCol = 1
    )

    saveWorkbook(my_df, file = mypath,
                 overwrite = TRUE)
    
    
    })  
  
  
  
  output$table <- renderTable(
    input$appts_data
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```